# How are YouTube and Google accessing each others cookies?

Tags: http, cookies

A lot of researching on stackoverflow told me that getting/setting cookies from other domains isn't possible.

but I can see youtube.com is doing that with google.com
[image]

How are they doing that then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first statement is correct - it is not possible to get/set cookies from other domains.

That list of cookies shows what was set when you viewed the page, but you must remember that the page includes resources from different locations (images and scripts).  When a script or an image is pulled from a different server, it has the opportunity to set a cookie as well.  Although the page on youtube.com caused all of those cookies to be set, it only has access to the ones actually on youtube.com.

Answer (score 1):

It uses google accounts for user logins which requires a visit to the google.com domain to authenticate the login which will then download the cookie. That cookie will not be sent to youtube.com, only to google.com for login and authentication purposes. The list that Google Chrome shows lists all of the cookies loaded for the entire request, it is not just limited to the domain of the site you are viewing and since youtube.com loads files from other domains it also pulls in any cookies from there as well.

Comment: you are saying in your answer that this happens due to the OAuth2.0 flow which occurs when I login. But I have already logged in along time ago, that screenshot taken was on a random video opened.
Moreover, in the OAuth flow an there is an HTTP redirection, and HTTP is stateless, therefore the browser at this page should be completely unaware of cookies changed/set in any page before.

Comment: There is HTTP redirection but eventually when you hit the main page there will be some element on there that points to google.com (ctrl+f view source for google.com and you will find a few), all of these will have the google.com cookie sent to it.